# Opencv cv::Scalar is not define

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a reference problem with my project according to OPENCV / CUDA.

Previously everything worked fine, but now that I have restarted the computer, I have a reference error causing more than 1400 Errors.

In my VS2017 project properties I have set :

**C/C++** 
Additional Include Directory : C:\opencv\opencv-3.4.0-Cuda\include

**Linker** 
Additional Library Directories : C:\opencv\opencv-3.4.0-Cuda\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_world340d.lib 
Additional Library Directories : C:\opencv\opencv-3.4.0-Cuda\x64\vc15\lib

In my main.h file I have for example

`#include "Marker.h"
 using namespace std;`

`cv::Scalar low_blue = cv::Scalar(95, 50, 100);`

With the following error "namespace cv has no member Scalar"

OR

`float GetMaxDistance(cv::RotatedRect rectangle, cv::Point2f &centerEnd);`

With the following error "namespace cv has no member RotatedRect  or Point2f"

If you could give me a hint, it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I am not an expert, but did you also try including types.hpp ? or/and even cv.hpp and cores.hpp? RotatedRect, Point2f and Scalar are defined in types.hpp .

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typographical error. If this is not the case, please, include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Note the word _Minimal_, you don't need to show us 4 declarations of `cv::Scalar` typed variables, if a single such declaration triggers the error message as well.

Comment: where are you including `cv`?

Comment: Thanks for all your support, i'm currently looking to install the new opencv, maybe my folder where I have opencv that works with CUDA has something missing.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki i'm using a `using namespace cv` in my main but still have a `namespace "cv" has no member "Mat`

Comment: I had to reinstall the VS2017 component cause a referenced .h were changed by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall the VS2017 component cause a referenced .h were changed by mistake